# Python factory dynamic instantiation

Tags: python, factory, instantiation

I am a C# programmer, and I am looking to make a simple factory. Observe the appempt:

```py
class ShapeFactory:
    _registry: Dict[ShapeType, Shape] = {
        ShapeType.Shape: lambda: Shape(),
        ShapeType.Circle: lambda: Circle(),
        ShapeType.Square: lambda: Square()
    }

    def Create(self, key: ShapeType) -> Shape:
        if key in self._registry:
            return self._registry.get(key)
        raise KeyError(key)

    def Register(self, key: ShapeType, value: Shape) -> None:
        if key not in self._registry:
            self._registry[key] = value
        raise KeyError(type)
```

The issue is that `Create` will always return the same instance of, say, `Circle`. How can I implement a means to dynamically instantiate an object, while allowing OCP?

Edit:
To further extend on my point; in C#, I would declare my dictionary as:

```cs
Dictionary<ShapeType, Func<Shape>> _registry = new Dictionary{
    [ShapeType.Shape] = () => new Shape(),
    [ShapeType.Circle] = () => new Circle(),
    [ShapeType.Square] = () => new Square()
}
```

This will always return a newly instantiated object for each value of the dictionary. This is the effect I wish to reproduce in python.

Comment: If you call ```Circle()``` ```n``` times, you will get ```n``` different instances

Comment: if I use (ShapeType is an Enum) `Create(ShapeType.Circle)` it will always return the SAME instance. I have confirmed this using `x is y`.

Comment: I think it might be because of the ```_registry``` you have defined. Have to tried something like a switch-case, to see if that works?

Comment: @AbhinavMathur if I use a switch, it breaks OCP. I need it to be dynamic and open for extension. A switch statement would do the job because it would run a new path of code, but this is NOT what I am asking for.

Comment: I'm not suggesting it as a solution, just using it to check if the issue lies in the ```registry``` you have defined

Comment: Then yes, the issue is in the `_registry`. I am not sure how to implement a means to dynamically instantiate a new object. I would have thought that `lambda` would wrap the execution, as `Func` does in C#, but it doesn't seem to.

Comment: You didn't actually call the constructor, you're testing the lambda. You want `self._registry.get(key)()`

Comment: @flakes Ah!!! Thank you! This makes total sense!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got some larger issues in this design.

First off if you have a mutable attribute in the class, you should define `_registry` in the `__init__` method of the class (isolated to the instance).

Next, the type attribute to `_registry` is wrong. You have a `dict` of `lambda`, not of `Shape` instances. You need `Dict[ShapeType, Callable[[], Shape]]`. The `Register` method has a similar problem.

You should also follow PEP 8 rules for naming. Try this:

```py
class ShapeFactory:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._registry: Dict[ShapeType, Callable[[], Shape]] = {
            ShapeType.Shape: lambda: Shape(),
            ShapeType.Circle: lambda: Circle(),
            ShapeType.Square: lambda: Square()
        }

    def create(self, key: ShapeType) -> Shape:
        if key in self._registry:
            return self._registry[key]()
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)

    def register(self, key: ShapeType, value: Callable[[], Shape]) -> None:
        if key not in self._registry:
            self._registry[key] = value
        else:
            raise KeyError(key)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for these details! I am a C# programmer, so this helps immensly!

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin Glad to help!

Comment: @TimeTravelPenguin by the way, you can catch these types of errors quickly by using tools like [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/). It would have warned you about the dict being typed incorrectly. I run it in all of my CI for Python along with `black`, `flake8` and `pytest`

Answer (score 1):

A simple, pythonic way of dynamically creating objects is:

```
class C:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "C"
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = "D"

dic = {"C": C, "D": D}
x1 = dic["C"]()
x2 = dic["C"]()
print(x1 is x2)    #prints False
```